# Access 2010 Conditional Formatting Generating Correct and Incorrect Results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database containing a continuous form. As part of this continuous form is a 'date this was last updated' field.

The form contains the conditional formatting to show dates older than 91 days with red text, which is tested and working on a separate form, however, I cannot see why this should be operating differently.

The coding is:

```
Field Value is | less than or equal to | Date()-91
```

Any date equal to or before 19/08/2019 should be in red, but it's not:
[image: Any date equal to or before 19/08/2019 should be in red, but it's not:]

Can anyone suggest why this is not working on this form, but working in the other, or suggest an alternative formula?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like those "dates" are text, not true date values as these would be right-aligned.

Comment: You are showing dates in international format. That could be contributing to issue. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: @Gustav - you got it! I can't believe I overlooked the temporary table data! I also can't believe I slaved over this for two hours yesterday without checking that... what an idiot.